# SQLite select statement pulls all values although it is not supposed to

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select, database-design

I have these three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "item" (
    "itemID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
    "itemName" VARCHAR(25), 
    buyerID INTEGER REFERENCES buyer(buyerID), 
    sellerID INTEGER REFERENCES seller(sellerID)
);

CREATE TABLE buyer(
    buyerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR(25),
    lname VARCHAR(25),
    itemID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES item(itemID)
);

CREATE TABLE seller(
    sellerID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR(25),
    lname VARCHAR(25),
    itemID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES item(itemID)
);

Item table has:
1|Poly|1|1
2|Jute|2|2
3|Salt|3|3

Buyer Table has:
1|Buyer1|Polybuyer|1
2|Buyer2|Jutebuyer|2
3|Buyer3|Saltbuyer|3

SellerTable has:
1|Seller1|Polyseller|1
2|Seller2|Juteseller|2
3|Seller3|Saltseller|3
```

Now I want to do a select query where i want the itemName and the first and last names of the relevant buyers and sellers. Suppose I want the list of buyers and sellers for salt. I will query:

```
SELECT buyer.fname, buyer.lname, itemName, seller.fname, seller.lname 
FROM buyer, seller, item 
WHERE item.itemID = 3;
```

I will expect this to return:

```
Buyer3|Saltbuyer|Salt|Seller3|Saltseller
```

But instead I get:

```
Buyer1|polybuyer|Salt|Seller1|polyseller
Buyer1|polybuyer|Salt|Seller2|juteseller
Buyer1|polybuyer|Salt|Seller3|saltseller
Buyer2|jutebuyer|Salt|Seller1|polyseller
Buyer2|jutebuyer|Salt|Seller2|juteseller
Buyer2|jutebuyer|Salt|Seller3|saltseller
Buyer3|saltbuyer|Salt|Seller1|polyseller
Buyer3|saltbuyer|Salt|Seller2|juteseller
Buyer3|saltbuyer|Salt|Seller3|saltseller
```

So where am I messing up? Is it a bad database design or a bad query or both? Thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `JOIN` to combine those 3 tables properly based on their primary key-foreign key relation, for example :

```
SELECT buyer.fname, buyer.lname, itemName, seller.fname, seller.lname 
FROM item
    INNER JOIN seller on item.itemID = seller.itemID
    INNER JOIN buyer  on item.ItemID = buyer.itemID
WHERE item.itemID = 3;
```

Comment: FOREIGN KEY constraints are used *only* when changing the database; in queries, you have to write the joins by hand.

Comment: Or use USING to join on specified common columns, leaving just one in the result. And NATURAL JOIN does that for all common columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are pulling results from buyer and seller tables in one select, but you are not using any joins. In this case, carthesian result is computed (every buyer is being combined with every seller) hence there is everything in your result.
 Try making inner join on `buyer.itemID=seller.itemID` and your query should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, esp. har07, that answer works perfectly. FYI another thing that also seems to work is:

```
SELECT buyer.fname, buyer.lname, item.itemName, seller.fname, seller.lname
FROM buyer, seller, item
WHERE buyer.buyerID = item.buyerID AND seller.sellerID = item.sellerID;
```

I guess functionally both the statements are the same.